# alpha value in geom_point {ggplot2}

Tags: r, ggplot2

`ggplot2::geom_point` [documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_point.html) notes that *varying alpha is useful for large datasets*. The below snippet generates two plots for two alpha values:

```
library(ggplot2)
data("diamonds")
d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price))
d + geom_point(alpha = 1/10) # alpha = 1/10
d + geom_point(alpha = 1/20) # alpha = 1/20
```

How would one interpret the value of `alpha`? As the plots can be easily produced with the above snippet, I did not provide the plots (can provide should it be necessary).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `alpha` parameter controls transparency, with `alpha=0` completely transparent:

```
## No points are displayed
d + geom_point(alpha = 0)
```

and `alpha=1` solid.

```
## Solid points
d + geom_point(alpha = 1)
```

I tend to use `alpha=1/sqrt(nrow(diamonds))` as a starting point.